# Symfony access parameters from services.yaml in Entity

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, inject, symfony5, symfony-config-component

In Symfony 5.0 I need to access parameters defined in services.yaml inside an entity.
When injecting the parameter_bag in services.yaml into my entity like

```
App\Entity\MyEntity:
    class: App\Entity\MyEntity
    calls:
        - [setParameterBag, ['@parameter_bag']]
```

It works if I create a new entity with

$myEntity = new MyEntity();

Then the parameter bag is injected by using my function `setParameterBag(..)` in MyEntity.php defined as follows

```
private $params;
public function setParameterBag(ParameterBagInterface $params) {
    $this->params = $params;
}
```

But if the entity is loaded from the DB `$this->params` is null.
What is the right way (or any way) to inject the parameter bag into an entity?

Comment: If you need a parameter in an entity, maybe it should be a class constant instead. @Dezigo is right when he says "you should never inject anything into entities". But I don't like the idea with the setter. For everythings related to parameters, I suggest you to read this chapter of  symfony best pratices https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices.html#configuration

Comment: Entities are not services. Using dependency injection configuration for entities is wrong, and won't work.

Answer (score 4):

This approach is wrong, you should never inject anything into entities neither parameters nor classes.
Entities should store only data and should be independent of everything.

Every time when an entity is created via  'new', dependencies won't be added.

You have to call $this-get('serviceName') from you controller.

if you want to add parameter to an entity just use a setter.

```
public function setParam1($param1) {
    $this->param1 = $param1;
}
```

Comment: I need a config parameter in the entity to provide a custom directory namer for vich uploader. Vich uploader needs a property (or getter function) providing a path. And I want my path to be dependend on a config parameter. So - what exactly should I do instead of injecting the parameters as you seem to say this is wrong in any imaginable case...?

Comment: in this case, don't inject anything into an entity. You need to create a new service and inject that param into it. $service = new YourService(); (in yml) $service->doSoomelogic($entity);